# Why won't \tkzLabelAngle place the label in the correct angle?

Tags: tkz-euclide

In the following figure, I'm trying to label angle `(lA,A,oA)`, but no matter what I try the label winds up being in angle `(rA,A,B)`.  What's going on here?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetkzobj{all}

\newlength\aehlength
\setlength\aehlength{1in}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt},>={To[scale=2]}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (55:\aehlength);
  \coordinate (lA) at ($(A)+(180:\aehlength)$);
  \coordinate (rA) at ($(A)+(0:\aehlength)$);
  \coordinate (lB) at ($(B)+(180:\aehlength)$);
  \coordinate (rB) at ($(B)+(0:\aehlength)$);
  \coordinate (oA) at ($(A)!-1cm!(B)$);
  \coordinate (oB) at ($(B)!-1cm!(A)$);

  \foreach \mynA/\mypA/\mynB/\mypB in {A/2cm/B/2cm,lA/1cm/rA/1cm,lB/1cm/rB/1cm}
  {
    \draw[arrows=<->] ($(\mynA)!-\mypA!(\mynB)$) -- ($(\mynB)!-\mypB!(\mynA)$);
  }

  \foreach \myn/\myp in {A/90,B/90,lA/90,rA/90,lB/90,rB/90,oA/90,oB/90 }
  {
      \node[my dot] at (\myn) {};
      \node at ($(\myn)+(\myp:8pt)$) {\myn};
  }

  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.45](oA,A,lA) {$x$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.45](lA,A,oA) {$x$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.75](oB,B,rB) {$60^\circ$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a bug.  The calculations for the angle don't seem to take into consideration of where the *starting* side of the angle is.

Answer (score 2):

With pure tkz-euclide new version [CTAN v 3.01](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\def\aehlength{3}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(55:\aehlength){B}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](180:\aehlength){lA}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:\aehlength){rA}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](180:\aehlength){lB}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](0:\aehlength){rB}
  \tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=-1](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{oA}
  \tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=-1](B,A) \tkzGetPoint{oB}
  \tkzDrawLines[add=.5 and .5,<->](oA,oB rA,lA rB,lB)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,lA,rA,oA,rB,lB,oB)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above=3pt](A,B,lA,rA,rB,lB)
  \tkzLabelPoints[right=3pt](oA,oB)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.75](oA,A,lA) {$x$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.75](lA,A,oA) {$x$}     
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.75](oB,B,rB) {$60^\circ$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried with `tkz-euclide.sty` version `2020/01/23 3.01c`, but there are several errors that need fixing, as far as I can tell. First, you need to handle [PGF issue 710](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/710) by adding `\newif\iftkz@sawp@sc`, `\newif\iftkz@line@norme` and `\newif\iftkz@equi@show` in appropriate places. Second, `tkz-euclide` uses `\fpeval`, therefore a `\RequirePackage{xfp}` seems to be needed too. With these changes, I can compile your document without any error. Thanks!

Comment: @frougon Thanks for your remarks. Only one person tested my package and compiled all the docs without problem. tkz-base line 41 `\RequirePackage{xfp,fp}` . How did you install tkz-euclide? You need to install tkz-base too ! line 71 of tkz-base you have`\newif\iftkz@line@normed`, line 96 `\newif\iftkz@sawp@sc`. I think you don't have the last tkz-base

Comment: I took the whole `latex` subdir from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide.zip but there is no `tkz-base` inside this file, AFAICS.

Comment: You need to install the new `tkz-base`. I need to modify `tkz-euclide.sty` because it works with tkz-base 3.01

Comment: Thanks, it indeed all works fine if I install `tkz-base`. I just didn't know this was a package! My suggestion would be to mention it in the *Installation* section of `tkz-euclide`'s `README` file. `tkz-base` is mentioned, but not in this IMHO important place. :) If you agree, I can delete all my comments here.

Comment: @frougon Like you want. perhaps it's useful for other user with the same problem ! I placed a test in `tkz-euclide` with a message. I need to make an update the next week with some minor changes in a new version 3.02

Comment: As you wish. If you think the comments are useful, I'll let them in place. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  It'll be a few days until I get a chance to check it out on my computer.  But when I do, I'll let you know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether it is  a bug or feature, but use `\tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.45](lA,A,oA) {$x$}`. Note the minus sign in `pos`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetkzobj{all}

\newlength\aehlength
\setlength\aehlength{1in}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt},>={To[scale=2]}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (55:\aehlength);
  \coordinate (lA) at ($(A)+(180:\aehlength)$);
  \coordinate (rA) at ($(A)+(0:\aehlength)$);
  \coordinate (lB) at ($(B)+(180:\aehlength)$);
  \coordinate (rB) at ($(B)+(0:\aehlength)$);
  \coordinate (oA) at ($(A)!-1cm!(B)$);
  \coordinate (oB) at ($(B)!-1cm!(A)$);

  \foreach \mynA/\mypA/\mynB/\mypB in {A/2cm/B/2cm,lA/1cm/rA/1cm,lB/1cm/rB/1cm}
  {
    \draw[arrows=<->] ($(\mynA)!-\mypA!(\mynB)$) -- ($(\mynB)!-\mypB!(\mynA)$);
  }

  \foreach \myn/\myp in {A/90,B/90,lA/90,rA/90,lB/90,rB/90,oA/90,oB/90 }
  {
      \node[my dot] at (\myn) {};
      \node at ($(\myn)+(\myp:8pt)$) {\myn};
  }

  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.45](oA,A,lA) {$x$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.45](lA,A,oA) {$x$}         %%% <=== here
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.75](oB,B,rB) {$60^\circ$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The minus since in the `pos` is what I wound up doing.  But, that means I can't rely on `tkz-euclide` to get it right.  And, I'll have to proof my document each time to see whether the angles are labeled correctly.  This wouldn't be a big deal if it were only one or two angles, but I'm generating these things for problem sets.  So, this solution feels more like a hack.  I'll probably write my own macro to handle this.  If this is a feature, it's an annoying (and IMHO useless) one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution (to define my own angle bisector):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aeFindAngleBisector{\ae@find@angle@bisector}
\def\ae@find@angle@bisector(#1)(#2)(#3)[#4]{%%
  \bgroup
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%%
                            {\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%%
  \edef\ae@angle@start@position{\pgfmathresult}%%
  \pgfmathanglebetweenlines{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%%
                           {\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%%
                           {\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%%
                           {\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}%%
  \edef\ae@angle@between{\pgfmathresult}%%
  \pgfmathparse{(\ae@angle@start@position+\ae@angle@between/2}%%
  \xdef\ae@half@angle@bisector{\pgfmathresult}%%
  \coordinate (#4) at ($(#2)+(\ae@half@angle@bisector:10pt)$);
  \egroup
}%%
\makeatother
```

which takes an angle `ABC` and defines a point along the angle bisector inside the angle as defined counterclockwise around the vertex `B`.